# How to make Node.js wait on a function call containing a post request?

Tags: node.js, async-await, request, wait

I am new to Node.js and I cannot make the code wait to finish my call to askKB, which contains an http request.

I need askKB to finish first so that I can use the variable speechText but the the code after the function call runs before I get speechText back.

I also tried to play around with await/async but was not successful.

```
 handle(handlerInput) {
    var newQuestion = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.phrase.value;
    const speechText = askKB(newQuestion);// <-- I want this function finish first because I need the variable speechText

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Balance', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
```

Here is the askKB function:

```
function askKB(question){     
  var answer;
  var requestOptions = {
    url: host + route,
    headers: {
      //some code here
    },
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    json: { "question": question }
  };

  request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {     
        answer = body.answers[0].answer;          
    } 
    else {
      answer = "Sorry! something went wrong. Try again...";
    }   
  });
  return answer;
}
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use async - await functions, and of course, promises.

A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.

A Promise is in one of these states:

pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
fulfilled: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
rejected: meaning that the operation failed.

So this will give you the needed time before returning data.

If you don't want promises, you can still make your code work with asynchronous functions.

```
async function askKB(question){     
  var answer;
  var requestOptions = {
    url: host + route,
    headers: {
      //some code here
    },
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    json: { "question": question }
  };

  await(request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {     
        answer = body.answers[0].answer;          
    } 
    else {
      answer = "Sorry! something went wrong. Try again...";
    }   
  }));
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: This still doesnt work. The problem is that in that first code block inside  handle(handlerInput) {} the code is not run sequentially. Basically, it continues to the next line after I call askKB, before askKB finishes and returns a value. I tried it with and without the async/await in askKB and did not work. I also tried an async helper function in which I call await askKB, and that did not work either. Any ideas why the code is not sequential?

Comment: Try with Deferred: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred

Comment: That way, you can resolve the function promise or reject before move on to the next cycle. And this function: const speechText = askKB(newQuestion); (on the first portion of code), wrap it with await() (because that's the constant you need to resolve before it goes on)